# Fipy for 1D branched network

Tags: fipy, mesh-network

I wish to use Fipy for a network made of 1D branches. Does Fipy allow that kind of mesh? I have not been able to find a similar example.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FiPy's 1D meshes don't support branched topologies, but you can get the same effective result by concatenating 2D or 3D meshes that are only one cell wide, e.g.,

```py
mesh1 = fp.Grid2D(nx=10, ny=1)
mesh2 = fp.Grid2D(nx=1, ny=7) + [[4.], [1.]]
mesh3 = fp.Grid2D(nx=5, ny=1) + [[5.], [4.]]
mesh4 = fp.Grid2D(nx=4, ny=1) + [[0.], [6.]]
mesh = mesh1 + mesh2 + mesh3 + mesh4
```

[image: branched FiPy mesh]

Comment: Many thanks for your help! Then, there is no simple way of allowing a face to link more than two cells? Or could that be implemented (in a way that does not involve triplicating the face at the intersection to link the 3 cells two by two)?

Comment: No, a face is the boundary between two cells, by definition. In the 2D case I show above, you could have two branches off from the same cell, rather than staggered the way I illustrated. You could also make polygonal cells that allowed more branches from the same cell.